# How to get the total size in bytes for a particular table in Teradata?

Tags: teradata, teradatasql

I am trying to get an estimate of the size of the data for all rows combined in a given table in Teradata. I checked the documentation but I could not find any relevant information.

Comment: The actual size per AMP can be found in dbc.TableSizeV, includes data plus indexes.

Answer (score 1):

I often do the following query to obtain the table sizes.

```sql
SELECT
  DATABASENAME, TABLENAME, 
  SUM(CURRENTPERM)/(1024*1024*1024) AS size_in_GB
FROM
  DBC.TABLESIZE 
WHERE
  DATABASENAME = database
GROUP BY 1,2
ORDER BY 3
```

Comment: Please switch to `dbc.TableSizeV`, those old non-V-views are deprecated since TD14 and might return unexpected results.